# Vagrant + SSH + Bash + MySQL - run script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ssh, vagrant

I have a host, and a guest being run with vagrant. The guest has an SQL DB on it. I would like to modify some of the contents via script from the host.

Vagrant supports sending commands through to the guest via the `vagrant ssh -c "command"` option. I have used this before.

I am having trouble getting the syntax (and likely the string escaping) correct for trying to run an SQL UPDATE query through this interface.

This is what I have, and it is not updating the DB.

`vagrant ssh -c "mysql -u root -proot -e \"update wp_options set option_value='http://myNEWvalue' where option_value='http://myOLDvalue'\" mydbname"`

The output returned is usually a list of the SQL commands/options.

I have tried a few incarnations of this and googling, reading other answers, etc., so any help is appreciated.

EDIT: As per EtanReisner's comment, I have modified the query to:
`vagrant ssh -c "set -x; mysql -u root -proot -e \"update wp_options set option_value='http://myNEWvalue' where option_value='http://myOLDvalue'\" mydbname"`

Which in turns gives me this:

```
+ mysql -u root -proot -e update wp_options set option_value=http://myNEWvalue where option_value=http://myOLDvalue mydbname
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  --auto-vertical-output
                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                      result is wider than the terminal width.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent.)
  --character-sets-dir=name
                      Directory for character set files.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                      with --comments.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
  -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --default-character-set=name
                      Set the default character set.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  --enable-cleartext-plugin
                      Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)
  -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
  -G, --named-commands
                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                      internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                      named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                      otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                      Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                      disabled by default.
  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
                      Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
  --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
  -L, --skip-line-numbers
                      Don't write line number for errors.
  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
  --column-names      Write column names in results.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
  -N, --skip-column-names
                      Don't write column names in results.
  --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).
  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
                      default database is the one named at the command line.
  --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you don't supply an
                      option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
                      PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
                      etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
                      work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
                      option is disabled by default.
  -p, --password[=name]
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
                      memory).
  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
                      down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
                      history file.
  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
                      --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.
  -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
  --ssl               Enable SSL for connection (automatically enabled with
                      other flags).
  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
                      --ssl).
  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-verify-server-cert
                      Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
                      hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
                      default.
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
  --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
                      also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
                      --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
  --max-allowed-packet=#
                      The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
                      server.
  --net-buffer-length=#
                      The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.
  --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.
  --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
                      --safe-updates.
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.
  --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              (No default value)
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              3306
prompt                            mysql>
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         FALSE
socket                            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
user                              root
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Comment: What happens when you run that? Does `vagrant ssh -c` run the command it is given through a shell on the guest?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, and MySQL spits out the help/options list as if it didn't understand what it was being asked to do.

Comment: If vagrant handles its command correctly it looks like that should work. If it handles multiple commands that way you could try adding `set -x;` to the start of the command to see what the shell actually ends up executing.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the post with the output.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like something is mis-handling (or extra unescaping) the command on you. You could try using `\\\"` instead of `\"` for the inner quotes (or possibly `\\"` but I would doubt it).

Comment: This would be much easier if you connect to MySQL directly from the host. If you've tried that and it's not working, go on the guest, find `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/my.cnf`, change it to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, and restart MySQL. If it works, then your solution becomes `mysql -u root -proot < foo.sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead, which should solve the problems you're seeing with escaping:

`echo "update wp_options set option_value='http://myNEWvalue' where option_value='http://myOLDvalue'" | vagrant ssh -c "mysql -u root -proot mydbname"`